# How to visualize time trigger in activity diagramm?

Tags: uml

I'm drawing an activity diagramm and I'd like to know how draw a timed trigger. My process is that when a task is created it should be done immediatly when it has a high priority or once a week if it has a normal priority.

I know there is the `time signal` symbol but in all examples I saw it's combined with the `join`symbol as it's an addional condition not "a second starting point".

So is my diagram valid? If not how should I draw it?

[image: activity]

Comment: Should a high priority task still run every Monday after it runs immediately after being created? If not (and from your description, it looks like it should be run only once), I believe there is a mistake in the diagram.

Comment: Every task is only run once.

Comment: So... an important one runs once, immediately after being created, and a normal one runs only once, the first Monday following the creation of the task. Right? If I understand correctly your diagram, it's not what it's telling: rather, every task, independently of its priority, runs every Monday.

Comment: Yes right an important one is run immeditately after being created and the normal ons on next monday. That's what I'd like to visualize.

Comment: I don't know UML well enough to tell how this could be represented, but I believe the actual diagram represents rather the fact that every task will continue to run every Monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recapitulate the rules which are scattered between the question and the comments:

- When a task is created, an importance is assigned: either “high” or “normal”.
- A high priority task is executed immediately after being created, only once.
- A normal priority task is executed on Monday (possibly through a weekly cron job), only once.

The following diagram attempts to model those three rules:

[image]

The wait-style signal was inspired by a diagram [here](http://www.xenomity.com/entry/Summary-of-UML-2) (search for “Signal” section). It seems that the signal element is flexible, and can be used to indicate [a moment in time](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/activityDiagram.htm#Figure4DistributingSchedules), or a [duration since an event](http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/) (search for “Signals” once more), or a duration to wait (see the book reference below).

According to the part on signals in Martin Fowler (2003) *UML distilled - a brief guide to the standard object modeling language* 3rd ed., page 121:

> A time signal occurs because of the passage of time. Such signals might indicate the end of a month in a financial period or each microsecond in a real-time controller.

Notes:

- I took freedom linking the signal element vertically, because it made sense in my case. Every other diagram I've seen using signals had arrows going to and from the signal horizontally.
- If “Task is created” from your diagram is an actual event, you may want to represent it as an event, not a process.

Comment: Thank you not only for showing me my mistake but also for the detailed answer